htmx: Selecting multiple classes in hx-trigger
I have the following code (simplified):
<div hx-post="/handle" hx-trigger="click from:.test1,.test2" hx-swap="outerHTML">
    <div class="checkboxes">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="test1" name="checkbox1" checked/>
            <label for="checkbox1">Test 1</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="test2" name="checkbox2" checked />
            <label for="checkbox2">Test 2</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

The problem is that the request is only triggered if I click on test1 checkbox, if I click on the second nothing happens. I tried multiple syntaxes (including the one from this reddit post) but nothing works. I tried swapping the classes in the hx-trigger, it causes only the second checkbox to work, so it means only the first class is used. I could use the same class on all elements, but I want to figure out the way to specify multiple classes.

I'm now convinced it's a bug in htmx pertaining specifically to hx-trigger since hx-include with the same syntax works perfectly fine.

The comma has a special meaning in the hx-trigger attrib. Maybe try escaping the selector by putting it in parens: hx-trigger="click from:(.test1, .test2)". At least that’s what you’re supposed to do if you need spaces in the selector. Can’t test itright now

Btw the checkboxes in your example code don’t have the matching classes.

Thank you, the parenthesis syntax worked just as I wanted! Also fixed the classes in example, even though it was not the issue in my actual code.
